# How to route traffic to an IP to use wlan0 instead of tun0 in OpenVPN?

Tags: openvpn, routing

I'm running OpenVPN on Ubuntu 19.04. I have a VPN connection (OpenVPN) I need to keep up all day. However, there's an IP I want to route outside of the VPN tunnel. This IP should connect to wlan0 as if there wasn't a VPN tunnel open at all. How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

On my server, whenever i wanted to route some traffic outside the vpn connection i had to route it to my standardgateway ( the router in my lan ).

So lets assume your router / standardgateway has the ip 192.168.0.1 and you want to route all traffic between your computer an the ip 88.78.123.12 outside of the vpn:

```
sudo ip route add 88.78.123.12 via 192.168.0.1
```

should to the trick

Comment: Thank you. That worked great. I guess if the default gateway changes it won't work. And I assume I have to reissue the command after reboot?

Comment: yes, this is not a permanent / persistent change. I am not an expert in this section but here is some good explanation on how to achieve that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321695/243440 Perhaps you can also write some script that is triggered on startup or when the vpn connection is initialized. Perhaps you can also setup static routes inside your vpn-configuration, i don't know.